# Hibernate Search: facet on double doesnt return results

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search, facet

I'm trying to adopt Hibernate Search into my application, but i'm stuck at limiting the searchresults by a range facet, to limit results based on price ranges.

My code (snippets):

Product.java contains:

```
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = DoubleBridge.class))
@NumericField()
private double price = 0.0;
```

My search handler, building the price facet:

```
        FacetingRequest priceFacetingRequest = builder.facet()
            .name( "price" )
            .onField("price")
            .range()
            .below(10.0)
            .from(11.0).to(24.0)
            .from(25.0).to(49.0)
            .from(50.0).to(99.0)
            .from(100.0).to(199.0)
            .from(200.0).to(499.0)
            .from(500.0).to(999.0)
            .from( 1000.0 ).to( 1499.0 )
            .above( 1500.0 )
            .excludeLimit()
            .createFacetingRequest();

    facetManager.enableFaceting(priceFacetingRequest);
```

And finally, before listing the results, limiting the results via one of the facets:

```
facetManager.getFacetGroup( "price" ).selectFacets( rangeFacet );
```

I've tried all rangeFacets possible, but none return any results. 
Besides the range() facet, i have different text facets which operate the same, but do filter the results normally.
Also, the facetManager resports results for the facetRange results, but trying still it results in 0 results when calling fullTextQuery.list().

What am i missing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a FieldBridge which transcribes the double to a string ;

```
public class CoreDoubleBridge implements FieldBridge
{

@Override
public void set(String s, Object o, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions)
{
    if (o instanceof Double)
    {
        NumericField field = new NumericField(s, Field.Store.YES, true);
        field.setDoubleValue((Double)o);
        document.add(field);

        Field fieldForFacet = new Field(s + ".facet", Double.toString((Double)o), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
        document.add(fieldForFacet);
    }
}
```

}

And annotated the price property with:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = CoreDoubleBridge.class)
private Double price = 0.0;
```

I hope this helps some other poor bastard looking for the solution to faceting Double values properly ;)